# What might be the difference between Zend Server Community Edition and Zend Server with no licence?

Tags: php, php5, zend-server, zend-server-ce

What might be the difference between "Zend Server Community Edition" and "Zend Server" with no licence (or an expired licence)?

My trial licence on my Zend Server has expired - so is that install now the same as the Community Edition?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Zend Server without a license (or with an expired license) is the same as Zend Server Community Edition.

"If you use Zend Server without a license (or if your license expires), you will still be able to use the basic product functionality, however features such as monitoring, diagnostics and updates will be disabled."
http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/license